# Graph API setting Sharepoint Online permissions failing

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

We have a system that uses a background service to set the permissions on newly created SharePoint Online documents using the .Net Graph SDK.  Seemingly at random, our action fails with an UnknownError response and we are not sure where to go from there.

We have tried to reproduce the issue on demand, but we have only experienced the issue on the non-interactive background service.  The background service performs this action many more times than we are able to attempt to perform on-demand, so it makes sense that it would occur more in that scenario.

```c#
var driveRecipients = new List<DriveRecipient>();

// Code that adds recipients
// var recipient = new DriveRecipient { Email = "..." };
// driveRecipients.Add(recipient)

var roles = new List<string> { "write" };

var inviteResult = await graphClient
    .Drives[driveId]
    .Items[fileId]
    .Invite(driveRecipients, true, roles, notifyUsers, "Automated SharePoint permission added by app X")
    .Request().PostAsync(cancellationToken);

return inviteResult;
```

Normally, we would receive an IDriveItemInviteCollectionPage result, but when the error occurs, an exception is thrown similar to this (since the service is non-interactive, we only have access to the logged serialized exception):

```js
Exception: {
       Data: [
       ]
       Error: {
         AdditionalData: null
         Code: UnknownError
         InnerError: {
           AdditionalData: {
             date: 2019-09-06T19:08:23.0000000
             request-id: 607a5beb-6742-45c7-893f-9352242c70d4
           }
           Code: null
           InnerError: null
           Message: null
           ThrowSite: null
           _typeTag: Error
         }
         Message:
         ThrowSite: null
         _typeTag: Error
       }
       HResult: -2146233088
       HelpLink: null
       InnerException: null
       Message: Code: UnknownError

Inner error

       ResponseHeaders: [
         {
           Key: Cache-Control
           Value: [
             private
           ]
           _typeTag: KeyValuePair`2
         }
         {
           Key: Transfer-Encoding
           Value: [
             chunked
           ]
           _typeTag: KeyValuePair`2
         }
         {
           Key: request-id
           Value: [
             607a5beb-6742-45c7-893f-9352242c70d4
           ]
           _typeTag: KeyValuePair`2
         }
         {
           Key: client-request-id
           Value: [
             607a5beb-6742-45c7-893f-9352242c70d4
           ]
           _typeTag: KeyValuePair`2
         }
         {
           Key: x-ms-ags-diagnostic
           Value: [
             {"ServerInfo":{"DataCenter":"West US 2","Slice":"SliceC","Ring":"4","ScaleUnit":"000","RoleInstance":"AGSFE_IN_3","ADSiteName":"WUS2"}}
           ]
           _typeTag: KeyValuePair`2
         }
         {
           Key: Duration
           Value: [
             10019.4936
           ]
           _typeTag: KeyValuePair`2
         }
         {
           Key: Strict-Transport-Security
           Value: [
             max-age=31536000
           ]
           _typeTag: KeyValuePair`2
         }
         {
           Key: Date
           Value: [
             Fri, 06 Sep 2019 19:08:22 GMT
           ]
           _typeTag: KeyValuePair`2
         }
       ]
       Source: Microsoft.Graph.Core
       StackTrace:    at Microsoft.Graph.HttpProvider.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Graph.BaseRequest.SendRequestAsync(Object serializableObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken, HttpCompletionOption completionOption)
   at Microsoft.Graph.BaseRequest.SendAsync[T](Object serializableObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken, HttpCompletionOption completionOption)
   at Microsoft.Graph.DriveItemInviteRequest.PostAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at <...>
   at <...>
       StatusCode: GatewayTimeout
       TargetSite: Void MoveNext()
       _typeTag: ServiceException
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank you for providing the diagnostic info! Your client code is not the problem. This is probably a transient server issue.

Upgrade your version of the Microsoft Graph .NET client library to version 1.17.0 as we introduced auto retry on 504 errors. You should see this issue solved with the upgrade. Let us know if you don;t.